# OCaml regular expressions and avoiding "try ... with"

Tags: string, pattern-matching, ocaml

I am completely new to OCaml. I need to search for numbers in line strings. I am using Str.search_forward to do this. See snippet of code below. What I have coded works, but another OCaml programmer said that using try ... with is bad OCaml practice. I could use `Str.string_match`, but then I would have to iterate over every character in the string using that character's position to test for a match. That seems a lot more inefficient then what I'm doing.

Please advise me on how I can use a regular expression in OCaml to possibly match numbers in a string without using `try ... with`. Thanks !

```
let find_page_hdr linestr =
    let r1 = Str.regexp "[0-9]+" in
    let pos =
        try
            Str.search_forward r1 linestr 0
        with Not_found -> -1
    in
    if pos >= 0
    then int_of_string (Str.matched_string linestr)
    else -1;;
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `try ... with` is bad OCaml programming practice. Your code would probably be a little tidier if you move the `try ... with` outward a little bit. Something like this might be good:

```
let find_page_hdr linestr =
    try
        ignore (Str.search_forward (Str.regexp "[0-9]+") linestr 0);
        Some (int_of_string (Str.matched_string linestr))
    with Not_found -> None
```

You can use a "local open" to remove some clutter:

```
let find_page_hdr linestr =
    let open Str in
    try
        ignore (search_forward (regexp "[0-9]+") linestr 0);
        Some (int_of_string (matched_string linestr))
    with Not_found -> None
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, about the `try ... with` being bad practice, your friend probably mentioned that it mainly was a matter of relying on the type safety. However, using negative integer "C-style" is consider even worse as it breaks type safety *and* has no well-defined semantics.

It would probably be preferred to return an `option` type in your code than that `-1` "special value".

As for your specific problem, I think you can have your answer in... `Str.split`.

```
let get_all_ints s =
  List.map int_of_string (Str.split (Str.regex "[^0-9]+") s);;
```

Would that work for you?